# What's wrong with this Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I have some Java code with a Scanner. What am I doing wrong as I am getting errors.

```
// Creates a "scanner" for the input
Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

// Print out random integer and open close message.
System.out.println("Printing Random Numbers between 1-200: ");
int guess = readInput.nextInt();
```

Errors (I am fairly new to Java, well I coded quite a bit like 4-5 years ago. but forgot):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at main.files.mian.main(mian.java:30)
```

Comment: You are not passing value that can be converted to an int. What are you passing from user input?

Comment: @RohitJain, I don't get what you mean, sorry. Could you explain further?

Comment: You need to pass in a valid integer...

Comment: @Script47: this error means: you tell me to read an int, but the next token is not an int at all. For example, if you type "hello", you will get this exception, because hello is not an int. 5, 78, or even 765 would do fine.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks for the clear explanation of this error. I read the "InputMismatch" part and realised that it might be something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type in anything other than a number (integer), your program crashes. The following code checks if it's able to convert the input into a int. If yes, everything is ok, otherwhise the error will be printet, but the program doesn't crash.

```
        // Creates a "scanner" for the input
        Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Print out random integer and open close message.
        System.out.println("Printing Random Numbers between 1-200: ");
        try {
            int guess = readInput.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("You didn't enter a number.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was just about to learn about error handling and you included it in this example, much appreciated.

Comment: I want to, and I have tried to, but It says wait. As soon as I can I will without doubt! Thanks mate. :) One last thing, why the System.err and not System.out?

Comment: Allright! I like to print out outputs (that are not part of the main application flow) onto the error console (they appear red in the eclipse console for example) so that they are more visible to me when I scroll through the log output of a program.

Comment: I know I said one last thing but, I needed to import the error, is that normal? This will be the last thing, but how do I if the custom error is returned then let user do the input part again?

Comment: Yes, that's normal. If the import is missing, the class InputMismatchException would not be found by the compiler. You can do a loop around the try-catch block and abort the loop as soon as the user enters a valid number.

Comment: @micro.widmer, What loop would you recommend, or is any fine? I meant import.

Comment: This shouldn't transform to a chat. Try out [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) which gives you a few examples about loops in Java. I'd recommend using a do…while loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35227/discussion-between-script47-and-mirco-widmer), Thanks for all this, helps a lot. :)